# Calling OpenCV methods from vuforia

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, android-ndk, vuforia

I am trying to do image processing on images that i get from camera frames with Vuforia QCAR. And for that i want to use OpenCV.

I want to send the pixels as byte arrays to openCv from Vuforia. But i dont know how to do it. I know how to reach java methods from native part or vice versa, but i couldnt find a starting point about how to call a native function from another library.

One more question, can i just invoke the OpenCV methods in native(c++) part of Vuforia? So that i dont have to just send the bytes to another class?

I am a bit confused

Thanks

Comment: i don't get it. are you using Vuforia just to get camera feed?

Comment: I am using vuforia for the AR purpose. I am going to get the camera frame. Do ocr on it and accoring to the result i am going to create some animation on AR

Comment: it makes no sence. vuforia already can do ocr. why not using that feature and just using for camera feed.

Comment: vuforia doesnt have support for digit recognising. I need to ocr on lottery ticket numbers, and with only Vuforia unfortunately i cannot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can work with OpenCV strictly in native code along with Vuforia. It's not totally clear if what you're trying to do is in real-time or not, however, it'll be more efficient if you do the computer vision stuff in C/C++.

Here's an example of how you could create an OpenCV Mat using a QCAR::Image.

```
Mat grayImage = Mat(QCARImage->getHeight(), QCARImage->getWidth(), CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)QCARImage->getPixels());
```

Once you instantiate the Mat with a pointer to the QCAR image data, you can go about doing image processing and computer vision as you normally would with OpenCV.